# Moderncv - Date left to subsection

Tags: moderncv

would it be possible to place the date left to Company in the section "Professional experience"?

Here my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,%                        % corpo del font: ci sono anche '10pt' e '12pt' 
               a4paper,%                     % carta A4
               sans,%                        % famiglia di font: c'è anche 'roman'
               ]{moderncv}                   % buona classe per CV
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                     % codifica dei font:
                                             % richiede una distribuzione completa di LaTeX,
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                  % codifica di input:
                                             % va accordata con le preferenze dell'editor
\usepackage[german]{babel}                  % per scrivere in italiano
\usepackage{microtype}                       % microtipografia
\usepackage{lipsum}                          % genera testo fittizio

\moderncvstyle{classic}                      % tema di moderncv:
                                             % oltre a 'classic', ci sono 'casual' (predefinito), 'oldstyle' e 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{blue}                         % colori di moderncv:
                                             % oltre a 'blue' (predefinito), ci sono 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple',
                                             % 'grey' e 'black'
\nopagenumbers{}                            % decommenta per disabilitare la numerazione automatica delle pagine
                                             % per CV più lunghi di una pagina
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}            % imposta i margini
\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{fax}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\restoresymbol{MARV}{fax}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
%
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.1cm}          % regola la larghezza della colonna con le date
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}
\firstname{{\huge{firstname}}}                % nome
\familyname{familyname}                        % cognome
\title{Curriculum vitae}                     % titolo del CV (opzionale: rimuovi la riga se non lo desideri)
\address{Street}{City}     % indirizzo (opzionale)
\mobile{0123~456~789~00}                     % cellulare (opzionale)
\email{~name\_surname@mail.com} % indirizzo e-mail
\renewcommand\emailsymbol{\Email}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Persönliche Angaben}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Geburtsort: Ort}{Geburtsdatum: Datum}{}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Ledig}{Nationalität: Nationalität}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\section{Professional experience}
\subsection{Company}
%
\cventry{08/2014 -- today}{Titel}{}{}{}{}
\cvitem{function}{
\begin{itemize}
\item task
%\item 
\end{itemize}
}{}
%

\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the command `\subsection` or better create a new command `\mysubsection` for your case.

The original definition for command `\subsection` for version 2.0.0 of `moderncv` class is:

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\subsection}{sm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
```

We can now define a new command `\mysubsection` with (because we have to add this code to the preamble we need the commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because `@` is used in the definition):

```
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysubsection}{mm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{#1}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother
```

Now you can call your special subsection with:

```
\mysubsection{08/2014 -- today}{Company}
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[%
  11pt,
  a4paper,
  sans,
]{moderncv}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\nopagenumbers{}

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}

\usepackage{footmisc}
\usepackage{savesym}
\savesymbol{fax}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\restoresymbol{MARV}{fax}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
\makeatother
%
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.1cm}          % regola la larghezza della colonna con le date
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysubsection}{mm}{%
  \par\addvspace{1ex}%
  \phantomsection{}% reset the anchor for hyperrefs
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{#2}%
  \cvitem[0ex]{#1}{\strut\subsectionstyle{#2}}%
  \par\nobreak\addvspace{.5ex}\@afterheading}% to avoid a pagebreak after the heading
\makeatother

\firstname{{\huge{firstname}}}                % nome
\familyname{familyname}                        % cognome
\title{Curriculum vitae}                     % titolo del CV (opzionale: rimuovi la riga se non lo desideri)
\address{Street}{City}     % indirizzo (opzionale)
\mobile{0123~456~789~00}                     % cellulare (opzionale)
\email{~name\_surname@mail.com} % indirizzo e-mail
\renewcommand\emailsymbol{\Email}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\section{Persönliche Angaben}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Geburtsort: Ort}{Geburtsdatum: Datum}{}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Ledig}{Nationalität: Nationalität}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\section{Professional experience}
\subsection{Company}
%
\cventry{08/2014 -- today}{Titel}{}{}{}{}
\cvitem{function}{
\begin{itemize}
\item task
%\item 
\end{itemize}
}{}
%

\section{Professional experience 2}
\mysubsection{08/2014 -- today}{Company} % <==============================
%
\cventry{}{Titel}{}{}{}{}
\cvitem{function}{
\begin{itemize}
\item task
%\item 
\end{itemize}
}{}
%
\end{document}
```

you get the wished result:

[image: wished result]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is easily possible using the `subsection` command. However, you can mimic its output as shown in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,
               a4paper,% 
               sans,%
               ]{moderncv}                
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                         
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                       
\usepackage[german]{babel}                
\usepackage{microtype}                  

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue}                                          
\nopagenumbers{}                          

\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}         
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3.1cm}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\cventry}{.\strut}{\strut}{}{}

\firstname{{\huge{firstname}}}
\familyname{familyname} 
\title{Curriculum vitae} 
\address{Street}{City}
\mobile{0123~456~789~00}
\email{~name\_surname@mail.com}
\renewcommand\emailsymbol{\Email}

\begin{document}
\section{Professional experience}
\cventry{08/2014 -- today}{\normalfont\large\textcolor{color1}{Company}}{}{}{}{}%
\end{document}
```

[image]